# How to overcome ( SQL Like operator ) performance issues?

Tags: sql, sql-server, sql-server-2008, search, sql-like

I have **`Users`** table contains about 500,000 rows of users data

The Full Name of the User is stored in 4 columns each have type **`nvarchar(50)`**

I have a computed column called **`UserFullName`** that's equal to the combination of the 4 columns

I have a `Stored Procedure` searching in **`Users`** table by name using **`like operatior`** as below

```
Select * 
From Users 
Where UserFullName like N'%'+@FullName+'%'
```

I have a performance issue while executing this SP .. it take long time **:(**

***Is there any way to overcome the lack of performance of using Like operator ?***

Comment: Try covering index in 4 COLUMNS ? Run query in query analyser, this will also help.

Comment: Why do you need to use `LIKE`?  What extra text does the `UserFullName` field have compared to `@FullName`?

Comment: Client need to search by any part of the name to get any user that his fullname contain this part

Answer (score 1):

Not while still using the like operator in that fashion. The % at the start means your search needs to read every row and look for a match. If you really need that kind of search you should look into using a full text index.

Answer (score 0):

Make sure your computed column is indexed, that way it won't have to compute the values each time you `SELECT`

Also, depending on your indexing, using `PATINDEX` might be quicker, but really you should use a fulltext index for this kind of thing:
http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms187317.aspx

Answer (score 0):

If you are using index it will be good.

So you can give the column an id or something, like this:

```
Alter tablename add unique index(id)
```

Comment: Please write "you" and not "u", this is not SMS.

Answer (score 0):

Take a look at that article http://use-the-index-luke.com/sql/where-clause/searching-for-ranges/like-performance-tuning .

It easily describes how LIKE works in terms of performance.

Likely, you are facing such issues because your whole table shoould be traversed because of first % symbol.

You should try creating a list of substrings(in a separate table for example) representing k-mers and search for them without preceeding %. Also, an index for such column would help. Please read more about KMer here https://en.m.wikipedia.org/wiki/K-mer .

This will not break an index and will be more efficient to search.